# Anonymous function with take-while not working?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

A simple example should demonstrate my problem:

```
First I define a simple variable:
(def a '(["one" 1] ["two" 2] ["nine" 9]))

;; CASE 1: (This works correctly)
(take-while #(< (second %) 5) a)
Returns: (["one" 1] ["two" 2])

;; CASE 2: (This does not seem to work correctly)
;; The only difference is the '>' instead of '<'
(take-while #(> (second %) 5) a)
Returns: ()
```

It seems to me that CASE 2 should return (["nine" 9]) ?

Is there a way to debug this to see what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`take-while` stops after the first failing test. Since the first element fails the test (it isn't greater than five), it never gets to the last one. If you want all elements that pass the test regardless of where they appear in the sequence, use `filter` instead.

Comment: 100% correct you are -- in fact once I looked at (source take-while), I can see that there is a (when ...) construct at the tail, which means that when pred is false the recursion stops.  Interesting... I thought that Clojure did not support tail recursion, so why is take-while coded recursively?  Hmmm...

Comment: take-while is not coded recursively ... it only *looks* like it is.  If you look carefully, you will see the entire body of `take-while` is wrapped in a `lazy-seq`.  `lazy-seq` is a macro that is used to construct lazy sequences.  Basically, the body of a `lazy-seq` is delayed until its value is needed.  So it's not really recursive at the machine level, but lazy evaluation via macros allow it to be described in a recursive way.

Comment: @NathanDavis, I'm not sure if that's correct (that `take-while` isn't "really" recursive). Clojure uses [locals clearning](http://clojure.org/lazy) to keep from blowing the stack, but it's still a recursive process. And if you prevent the locals clearing from working (e.g. by doing what's called "holding onto your head") you will indeed blow the stack. Put another way, `lazy-seq` makes it lazy and adds some related magic but doesn't change that it's recursive.

Comment: @DerrickJohnson, it's true that Clojure doesn't support *general* tail call elimination; you need to use `recur` to prevent stack frames from accumulating. However, Clojure has some extra "magic" in its implementation to support lazy sequences, which are often defined recursively. See [here](http://clojure.org/lazy) for more information.

Comment: @jbm: AFAIK `(lazy-seq (foo))` is expanded to something like `(clojure.lang.LazySeq. (fn [] (foo)))`. Since the body is stored as a function that is called when the LazySeq is forced rather than being immediately executed, that doesn't look like real recursion. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jbm, the locals clearing you are referring to has nothing to do with controlling the size of the stack.  Rather, it simply means that before the last function call of a function is executed, the locals of the calling function (at least the ones that aren't captured in a clojure) will be cleared (i.e., nulled out).  This prevents retention, e.g., of the head of a structure while the tail is being processed.  However, it allows *heap* memory to be freed, not stack.  Anyway, `lazy-seq` is definitely lazy.  That's why its called `lazy-seq`.  And `take-while` is implemented with `lazy-seq`.

Comment: @NathanDavis, [clojure.org/lazy](http://clojure.org/lazy) says: "Clojure does local-variable clearing on tail calls to ensure that no lingering references remain on the stack". That certainly makes it sounds like locals clearing has something to do with the stack.

Comment: @Chuck, but what makes it not really recursion? (I'm really asking, not being snide).  Do you mean because it's wrapped in a thunk? To my (admittedly informal) understanding that mean's it's not a tail call but not that it isn't recursion.

Comment: @jbm, yes, local clearing has something to do with the stack.  But it has nothing to do with the stack *size*.  That's what I'm saying -- locals clearing does not change the size of the stack, it just nils out local variables before making the last function call to avoid retaining references to unused objects on the *heap*.  If you have additional questions about this, I would suggest opening a new question where it can be discussed freely..

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments to `>` is important, try

```
(take-while #(> 5 (second %)) a)
;=> (["one" 1] ["two" 2])

(drop-while #(> 5 (second %)) a)
;=> (["nine" 9])
```